# Django-carton work with two Product models

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django-carton (https://github.com/lazybird/django-carton) and I wonder if it is possible to associate more than one model as a Product model.

Right now, I have a base class *Product* which I registered as my product model and I inherited *Pub* and *Restaurant* from it. The problem I face is, `cart.show()` basically returns all product objects in the cart which only have products attributes and not Pub's or Restaurant's, and I can not distinguish which one is Pub and which one is Restaurant.

Answer (score 1):

In your base model you can define method `get_type` without implementation, and in inherited classes, implement it, for example:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    def get_type(self):
        pass
    class Meta:
        ...
        abstract = True

class Pub(Product):
    ...
    def get_type(self):
        return 'pub'

class Restaurant(Product):
    ...
    def get_type(self):
        return 'restaurant'
```

If you know the type of an instance, you can easily access needed attributes.

Or you can use just `isinstance` built-in function:

```
if isinstance(obj, Pub):
    # Your logic here
```